# Maven: change the directory in which tests are executed

Tags: maven

In my code I have set to create some files in `./` directory, because when the software will be deployed in the installation machine, all the configuration files will be created in `./` if it's the first run

Unfortunately when I build the project, and Maven executes tests, all the files are created in the project directory.
I want those files to be created in `target/test-run/`
How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you are using the surefire plugin to execute tests (which is the default), then you can set working directory like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${java.io.tmpdir}</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Reference: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

To set to the specific directory in the question:

```
<workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-run</workingDirectory>
```