# How edit path-structure (jbehave, maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jbehave

Help, I've changed in the project folder structure and then do not run the test.
How to make Maven ran my folder structure, not by the standard?
I use IDE eclipse, Thucydides-JBehave archetype, maven.
This my log in ide:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Sample Thucydides project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Test_framework 
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Test_framework\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Test_framework ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @     
Test_framework ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Test_framework\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @  
Test_framework ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.11:test (default-test) @ Test_framework ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ Test_framework ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Test_framework\target\Test_framework-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.11:integration-test (default) @ Test_framework ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: C:\Test_framework\target\failsafe-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. build   
is platform dependent!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.382s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 22 12:56:14 EET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/175M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is structure of project:

```
Progect|
       |Pages|
       |     |HomePage.java
       |     |CategoryPage.java
       |Steps|
       |     |UserSteps.java
       |Story|
       |     |SomeTest.story
       |Tests|
       |     |SomeTest.java
       |JRE System Library [J2SE-1.5]
       |Maven Dependencies
       |pom.xml
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733633/maven-change-the-directory-in-which-tests-are-executed