# Maven fails to run unit tests on cloudbees

Tags: android, unit-testing, maven, cloudbees

I have a Maven based Android project setup for ci on cloudbees. My Jenkins job is just running the 'install' goal after retrieving the src from BitBucket. Everything builds fine. The only issue is that the unit tests fail to run.

Running exactly the same goal in IntelliJ (locally) does find and run the unit tests.

My pom looks like this -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.odl</groupId>
    <artifactId>GhostRunner</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>GhostRunner</name>

    <properties>
        <platform.version> 4.1.1.4
            </platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-alpha-1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-android</artifactId>
            <version>4.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                                        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The jenkins output like this -->

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) @ GhostRunner ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.15(default-test)
[JENKINS] Recording test results
mojoStarted com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0(default-emma)
```

Another interesting point is that I can remove the surefire dependency and the unit tests still run fine against the install goal in IntelliJ. For some reason Maven is just not seeing the tests when run from Jenkins on Cloudbees.

Wisdom received gratefully.

**Here's what cloudbees had to say ::**

> The issue here is that IntelliJ is compiling the test classes for you
>   and putting those classes into the
>   ${project.build.testOutputDirectory} for you.
>
> You can replicate this failure locally by getting IntelliJ to execute
>   clean install (hold ⌘ while clicking on the lifecycle goals)
>
> There are two ways to solve this problem.
>
> Tell Maven that your test sources are not in the standard place
>
> Put your test sources into the standard place.
>
> When you are dealing with lots of plugins, some of which not written
>   by the Apache Maven team or the Codehaus Mojo team, going with the
>   standard directory layout is the best way. Plugins subject to the
>   review of the Apache Maven or Codehaus Mojo communities will usually
>   pick up the changes when you tell Maven that you are using a
>   non-standard layout. Plugins not subject to that review process can
>   often not be aware of how to work correctly and as such you end up
>   forced to align with the standard layout.
>
> Stephen Connolly CloudBees, Inc

I've re-organized my project to reflect the Maven norm but it's still not running the tests on the cloudbees server.

Here's the relevant output from the jenkins console output ::

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ GhostRunner ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /scratch/jenkins/workspace/ghost runner/src/test/resources
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6(default-testResources)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0(default-testCompile)
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ GhostRunner ---
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0(default-testCompile)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.15(default-test)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) @ GhostRunner ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
```

I guess the important bit is

> No sources to compile

Somehow it still doesn't know where the tests are.

Comment: Where do you have located your unit tests? `src/test/java` and have you named them like [`*Test*.java`, `*Test.java` and `*TestCase.java`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes).

Comment: they are under /src/test and all are named in the format <classname>Test. Do you think having the java folder under the test folder is important?

Comment: Yes it is necessary, cause it's the [default in Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) `src/main/java` for production code `src/test/java` for unit tests. Furthemore `src/main/resources` for resources which can be used in production code and `src/test/resources` for resources in unit tests.

Comment: The guys at cloudbees back up what you are saying ::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments in your question above, it seems that you are not putting your test source files into the directory structure expected by Maven.  This is actually Maven configuration issue, and not directly related to CloudBees (except the CloudBees uses vanilla maven to run your build).  If you tried to run your own build locally via the maven 'mvn' command (like the CloudBees Jenkins CI job does), you should experience the same error.

Based on the [standard Maven directory structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), you should be placing the source for your tests in: *src/test/java*

If you want/need to change the default maven directory structure, there are typically configuration changes you can provide in the pom.xml to set these.  However, many people find that fighting against maven only leads to more pain and eventually go back the standards.

For more info, check out this stackoverflow thread about [how to change the default Maven tests directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733633/maven-change-the-directory-in-which-tests-are-executed).

Comment: That's the interesting thing. I've amended my project structure to place all the src code in the expected places (as commented above) and the tests still do not run on cloudbees. If I run from the cmd line locally with 'mvn clean' followed by 'mvn install' the tests all run. The issue does seem to be that for some reason the cloudbees build can't find the test sources.

Comment: Please open a support ticket at CloudBees and we can help you dig in.

Comment: Thanks to all at Cloudbees for helping me out. In the end the problem was ME. In re-arranging my project structure I had somehow managed to remove a large part of it (the source) from version control so it didn't show up as a 'change' in IntelliJ. Locally everything worked but the bitbucket repo was empty. Must try harder :)