# Maven: How to confine the application output to the target directory

Tags: maven

I have a java application that uses maven for build management.

When I run the generated application jar with

```
java -jar myjar
```

the output files generated by the application end up in the projects root directory. So if I execute the jar in /my/project/dir and create a filewriter to write to logs/mylog

The resulting file ends up in

```
/my/project/dir/logs/mylog
```

Exactly as expected.

HOWEVER:
When maven surefire plugin executes the unit tests, the files end up in the module directory. 
Say that i compile a maven project in /my/module.

The compiled files end up in /my/module/target/classes.
When maven executes these classes, through unit tests, the output of the same classes ends up in

```
/my/module/logs/mylog
```

I would like the files to end up in the target dir like

```
/my/module/target/logs/mylog
```

As this is where the class files reside.

So I am looking for a way to configure maven surefire to define the java classes' root directory to point to target instead of the module dir.

EDIT:
I have found this post:
[Maven: change the directory in which tests are executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733633/maven-change-the-directory-in-which-tests-are-executed)
That seems to attempt a fix to my problem. However, if i set the workingdirectory to my target dir, the tests can no longer find my resources, even if they are copied from the modules ${basedir} to ${basedir}/target

Comment: this is not clear, what `logs` are you talking about? Where do they come from, what creates them?

Comment: My application, when running as a jar outside maven, is placing its logfiles and such inside the projects root directory. This is as designed and not a problem. However, when MAVEN executes the program the files end up in the modules root dir, not in target, where the class files are. How do i fix that?

Comment: how are you running the application? are you using maven to run it or just java -jar ... or something else?

Comment: both: When i run with java -jar the files end up in the applications root directory. When i run with maven the same files end up in the maven modules directory (Where POM, src, target and so forth are located) I would like to configure maven so these files end up in target instead of the Module directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: 
By default, the maven surefire plugin executes its tests in the modules main directory.
In order to avoid this, set the workingdirectory of the plugin to the target directory.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <configuration>
         <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
         <basedir>${project.build.directory}</basedir>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Note that in case of tests that rely on some resources with root in the modules basedir, you need to copy these over. The easiest way i can find is with the resource plugin.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>dependency</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/dependency</targetPath>
        </resource>
...
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set your application working dir to ./target (or in a Maven property way: ${project.build.directory})

Comment: That would require me to make a change to the application itself. The project won't run inside a maven in production, so that would be a troublesome solution.

Comment: I was very unclear in my formulation before. I have edited my question.

Comment: What plugin do you use to "run" your application through Maven?

Answer (score 0):

#### I can't tell you exactly how to do what you need to do because there is no real information

I can give you a hint about what to look at using.

Maven [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) can change the source, and behavior of Maven when they are selectively enabled.

Profiles are specifically designed to do just what you want to do.

Comment: Actually, a profile shouldn't be necessary here. Maven should always direct the application root directory to target in this project.